# Temenos OFS fails with DUPLICATE.TRAP:1:1=TRUE

Tags: temenos

Temenos T24 (Transact) OFS message processing fails with the error "DUPLICATE.TRAP:1:1=TRUE":

```
ACLK2306051542/NB0000000002/-1,DUPLICATE.TRAP:1:1=TRUE
```

This happens when the same Message ID (NB0000000002) is provided in the OFS request message:

```
AC.LOCKED.EVENTS,/I/PROCESS//0,/NB0010001,/NB0000000002,ACCOUNT.NUMBER:1:1=1000001313,LOCKED.AMOUNT:1:1=461.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message reference is saved in table F.OFS.UNIQUE.MSG.REF (SQL name: F_OFS_UNIQUE_MSG_REF). By deleting the record from this table should solve the problem. Also, check the F.OFS.REQUEST.DETAIL table.